# why this code doesn't preload admob interstitial

Tags: android, admob

few days ago Admob stopped my ads inside one of my apps because it encourage users accidental clicks

here is my code

```
 interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.interstitial_ad_unit_id));
        AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest2);
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                displayInterstitial();
            }
        });
```

and

```
public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
```

shouldn't this code pre load the interstitial ads or not !?

Comment: in your code interstitial Ad  should be show, what is the problem ? ad not loaded ?

Comment: the ad appear correctly but admob says it is encourage accidental clicks ... !